# xaf how to show a listview when a record in listview is clicked

Tags: c#, listview, xaf

I have a SmsReport table which smses are recorded with the same packetid if they are sent at the same time. By using this id I want to show a listview and when a record is clicked I want the detailed listview to be shown(all the smss that has the clicked packetid). How can this be made possible in xaf?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NonPersistent ListView. See more at : https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113167